# Search using Facebook api?

Tags: php, facebook, search

Is it possible to search users of Facebook by gender, hometown and a group that he/she liked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry to disappoint you. its not (at the moment).
not however any user with no connection to you. if you obtain an access token you can do that for the friends and even friends of friends. if they have listed that data public or accessible to the user who authorized the token and gave you the permission.
you can as well view fans for a group as this data is public too but a "search" as you probably are looking for doesnt exists. sorry.
heres your documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#search

Answer (score 0):

Look up Facebook Graph API - it is pretty powerful in querying by various parameters.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#search